# jquery code completion and netbeans... not working, although done like in the manual

Tags: jquery, netbeans, autocomplete

Hey,
what i read on several help-pages, was, that getting jquery code completion to work, was just:

1. getting targeted browsers right (the
   only one i choose was firefox 3.x or
   later)
2. putting jquery file into project (it
   is now visible in "source files")
3. adding the "script type"etc.-line (tried filename with and without / before )

Did this... but still no code completion. Any ideas? Got windows 7 and netbeans 7, 32bit system.

Wtf is wrong? :(

http://www.loaditup.de/files/615138.png

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your source file ends with a ".js" extension before you open it in netbeans.  I made the mistake of copying some code into a text (.txt) file and then opening it in netbeans.  The code completion or auto-formatting did not work at all.  This was resolved when I resaved it as a ".js" file.

Answer (score 0):

Name the file "**jquery-1.7.1.js**" (for the newest version) and it will work. Just figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem until I made sure the file name was the same as the version in the file header. 
I.e.:
"jQuery JavaScript Library v1.8.0"   (second line of the file)
equals  "jquery-1.8.0.js" file name.
Worked for me